# Does an old Intel Core Duo Mac Mini have enough performance to run the latest Garageband?

Tags: mac-mini, performance, garageband

I am getting a used Mac Mini primarily so I can record music using Garageband.

Will the 2007 or 2009 models have enough performance to run the latest Garageband and latest OS X?

I will at most record three audio tracks simultaneously. For playback probably maximum six audio tracks plus maximum six software instrument tracks.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching and found this (http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20020233-263.html):

> As with all of Apple's new software, iLife '11 requires a Mac with an
>   Intel processor. iLife '11 is also only compatible with Mac OS X
>   10.6.3 or newer (the current version is 10.6.4). Your machine must also have at least 1GB RAM and about 5GB of available disk space
>   (though it is recommended that users retain at least 10 percent of
>   their hard drive space and leave it open).
>
> A DVD drive is required for installation, and users must have a
>   minimum screen resolution of 1,280 x 768 pixels.
>
> Some features of iLife '11 require greater minimum specifications.
>   GarageBand "Learn to Play" requires a Mac with an Intel Core 2 Duo or
>   better processor. 24-bit recording in GarageBand requires a 24-bit
>   audio interface that works with Mac OS X.

So I guess I will go for a Mac Mini with at least a Intel Core 2 Duo.